# rbenv: rails: command not found immediately after installing rails 5.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, rbenv

I have spent the whole day trying to upgrade from Rails 4x to 5.2.1. I was following [this](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra#homebrew) guide for the upgrade and I was not able to upgrade successfully.

**Issue:**
After "successfully" installing Rails 5 using:
 `ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin17]` and did `rails -v` I get:

```
rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.2.0
```

**Things that I have tried:**
`gem pristine different gems`
`gem pristine --all`
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316792/rails-rbenv-rails-command-not-found)
and played around with paths but no luck so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Additionally here is my gem environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.3 (2018-10-18 patchlevel 105) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Matt/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/Matt/Tools/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-17
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/Matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
     - /Users/Matt/Tools/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec
     - /Users/Matt/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /Users/Matt/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/Matt/.rbenv/bin
     - /Users/Matt/anaconda/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
     - /Users/Matt/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/Matt/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
```

Comment: It would help if you included the specific steps you took to get to where you are, not just including a link to a very long guide. That said, I never recommend rbenv and I always recommend RVM: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.5.3`; install Rails with `gem install rails`. Proceed from there. (and I'd recommend removing rbenv entirely before doing any of that)

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails`, your paths may not be setup correctly

Comment: @anothermh sometimes suggesting a different tool is the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: I came across this problem myself, and `gem pristine --all` did work and it solved the issue, just want to thank you for mentioning that as an option and making sure anyone else should try that before looking for other solutions.

Answer (score -2):

You installed `ruby` using `rbenv` and now you can install gems. and `rails` is a gem for `ruby`. So, first to set the global version of Ruby you should create `.ruby-version` file in your home directory and write your installed ruby version (`2.5.3`) on it.

and then you should run `gem install rails` command to install rails.